# Is it possible to configure a spring integration 'MessageHandlerChain' using only java annotations?

Tags: spring-integration

Xml configuration with namespace support allows nesting of handlers inside the handler chain tag like below:

```
<int:chain input-channel="input">
    <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-type="StringResult" />
    <int:service-activator ref="someService" method="someMethod"/>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter level="INFO" log-full-message="true"/>
</int:chain>
```

But I don't see how that can be achieved in an annotation-based configuration. Spring integration reference documentation doesn't show any example of annotation config in the `MessageHandlerChain` section (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain). So, I am wondering whether it is possible at all or if yes, please show me a sample config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Programming Tips and Tricks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips).

> If you are familiar with Spring Integration XML configuration already, starting with version 4.3, we provide in the XSD elements definitions the description with the pointer which target classes are used to produce beans for the adapter or gateway.

In this case:

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>
        Defines a Consumer Endpoint for the 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain'
        composed of a chain of Message Handlers.
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
```

The `MessageHandlerChain` `@Bean` gets a list of `MessageHandler`s.

You might also want to consider using the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) instead

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return f -> f.handle(...)
         .handle(...)
         .transform(...)
         .handle(...);
}
```

**EDIT**

It's not so convenient to use Java DSL for POJO services; you can wire in real `MessageHandler`s directly, but for POJO services, you need two `@Bean`s for each. Here's an example...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So45910254Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So45910254Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("input", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>("bar"));
        context.close();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler chain() {
        MessageHandlerChain chain = new MessageHandlerChain();
        chain.setHandlers(Arrays.asList(myPOJOMessageHandler(), logger()));
        return chain;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler myPOJOMessageHandler() {
        return new ServiceActivatingHandler(processor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingMessageProcessor<?> processor() {
        return new MethodInvokingMessageProcessor<>(foo(), "upCase");
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingHandler logger() {
        return new LoggingHandler(Level.INFO);
    }

    public static class Foo {

        public String upCase(String in) {
            return in.toUpperCase();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have seen XSD descriptions but it still seems impossible to configure a handler chain using annotations only. For example, annotation to configure a service activator is
`@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="hotDrinkBarista", outputChannel="preparedDrinks")
public Drink prepareHotDrink(OrderItem orderItem) { ...}`
This style of config doesn't give me a reference to `MessageHandler` bean and so it can't be added to a chain. 
The DSL configs are a neat alternative though.

Comment: No; you don't use the `@ServiceActivator`. See my edit; it's not so convenient for invoking POJO services but it can be done. The DSL is preferred.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot.